# jQuery cookie value is %5Bobject%20Object%5D

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a simple html page and a js script:
HTML page:

```
<body>
<input type="text" id = "content">
<button type="button" id="btn"> Save </button>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var cook = $.cookie('theName',  { path: '/'});
     if ( cook )
        alert(cook); 
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var theName = $('#content').val();
        alert(v.val());
        $.cookie('theName', theName, { path: '/', expires: 7 });
        alert("Cookie done");
    });
});
```

Libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"> </script>
```

It should save my name and when I hit refresh to show my name. The only problem is when I try to read the cookie, instead of name shows %5Bobject%20Object%5D.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried: var cook = $.cookie('theName'); ?

Comment: Yes, but then 'cook' is undefined.

Comment: `%5Bobject%20Object%5D` is `[object Object]`, i.e. the default string representation of an object.

Comment: I agree. But how can I get the value of the cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var cook = $.cookie('theName'); //get from cookie if exists
     if ( cook )
        alert(cook); 
    $('#but').click(function(){
        var theName = $('#content').val();
        alert(theName);
        $.cookie('theName', theName, { expires: 7, path: '/' }); //set the cookie
        alert("Cookie done");
    });
});
```

**Updated:**

try adding:

```
$.cookie.raw = true;
```

Comment: I already tried this, but without path when I read the cookie, the variable cook is undefined.

Comment: @AlinC $.cookie('your_cookie'); is used to get the value of cookie if its set, using path will set it

Comment: @AlinC try adding $.cookie.raw = true; as in my updated answer

Comment: thank you. But what does it mean cookie.raw = true?  Also do you have any idea why it works in WAMP server, but outside no? I mean cookies have nothing to do with the server.

Comment: @AlinC by default the cookie value is encoded/decoded when writing/reading, using encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent.. check in the Readme section of query.cookie.js

Answer (score 3):

```
var cook = $.cookie('theName',  { path: '/'});
```

This overwrites the cookie with the string representation of `{ path: '/'}`.

To actually retrieve the existing cookie just pass the name:

```
var cook = $.cookie('theName');
```

There is no point in passing the path anyway - if you are outside the path for which the cookie is set you simply don't get it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
{
c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
}
if (c_start == -1)
{
c_value = null;
}
else
{
c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
if (c_end == -1)
{
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Source:[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: w3schools is one of the worse resources. http://w3fools.com/. Why should he use this instead of a widely used jQuery plugin?

Comment: @FelixKling - Thank you for your Suggestion.

As per his cookie requirement query, this w3School suggested code works for his purpose. I agree the use of jquery plugins, but will leave it for Alin C to decide.

Comment: @Nathan Lee, thank you for your answer, but I intend to use jQuery.